# how to configure the batch job on weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing

I have created a standalone java application using quartz.i want to deploy the standalone program on weblogic so as it could be run as a batch job.
Can you please help me how could i deploy the java application on the weblogic and run the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this is create new thread and do your batch job in it.
You can add your class to Weblogic classpath and use it like start or shoutdown class.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/startup_shutdown.html) is link on oracle documentation.